# How to select last x columns where sum of value of a particular column is less than or equal to 100?

Tags: mysql, sql, api, logic

Please help me to write below case.

How to write mysql query to satisfy below conditions in below table:

Table represents: this table holds reviews.

review4 is stored in this table plus there are 3 more reviews (stored somewhere else) which were done before review4 and after review3 so count is 4 (review4 + 3 others), [this count keeps track of all the review, this means after review3 3 more reviews were done and then review 4 is done]. Similarly for 2nd row there are 4 reviews before review3 and after review2 so, count =5 (review2 + 4 others).

There is a different data source which contains review in between like for example: when count = 5 in row 1 it means 4 reviews between review4 and review 3 are stored in some other location, count field helps to have a track and further data processing which is not present here is done later.

Table is:

| sno. | userId | value | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | review4 | 4 |
| 2 | 34 | review3 | 5 |
| 3 | 34 | review2 | 5 |
| 4 | 34 | review1 | 1 |

Suppose I give offset = 3 and limit = 5 in above table so, it should return row 1 row2 , with lower_left_count =3 and upper_left_count = 1,
[this tells us to not pick last 3 reviews before review 4(including review 4) and review3 ].

- offset 4 and limit = 5, then return row2 and row3 with lower_left_count =0 and upper_left_count=5 , [this tells pick all reviews before review3 and review 3 too but don't include review2 or reviews before  it]
- offset 5 and limit = 5, then return row2 and row3 only with lower_left_count =1 and upper_left_count=4 , [this tells pick all reviews before review3 excluding review3 and review 2 and 4 reviews before  it too]
- offset 2 and limit = 10, then return row1,row2 and row3 only with lower_left_count =2 and upper_left_count= 2, [this tells pick all reviews after review3,review3 and 1 before review2 and review2 and  2 before review 4 too]

I am stuck with this for quite sometime now, if something is not clear please let me now.

Comment: sql fiddle please :) sample data and expected result help alot

Comment: I see only 4 rows. How any count can be 5 ?

Comment: @Serg I have added that info too.
actually count holds no. of reviews after last review + 1 (for review 4)

Comment: @AliFidanli I am very new to this I try to see how I can add it too.
I have mostly include all the required details in question only.